# CSS Styles not applying to ExtJS Button

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have added css styles to my buttons which are nested within a panel. However, the buttons are not appearing as transparent even if I put the !important tag in the css.

I have also tried adding addStyles/cls: tags to the button object but that hasn't worked either.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Button Code:

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
                text: month,    
                //cls: "test",
                handler: function(button){
                    var buttonMonth = button.text;
                    getGrids(buttonMonth);
                }
            });
            //button.addClass("test");
            panel.add(button);
```

CSS Class:

```css
.x-btn{
    font:normal 11px tahoma, verdana, helvetica;
    cursor:pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.x-btn button {
    border:0 none;
    background:transparent !important;
    font:normal 11px tahoma,verdana,helvetica;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    overflow:visible;
    width:auto;
    -moz-outline:0 none;
 }
```

Comment: 2 questions, 1 what extjs version are you using, and second the css class you written is the css the button curently has? or what you try to apply ?

Comment: You added the class "test" why not select it with that?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4. If you look, the class "test" is commented out because that didn't work with a previous css class. What do you mean by is the css class the css the button has? I tried adding the class to the button but saw this css in a blog that said it would apply to all buttons. Similar to x-grid3 for grid css

Comment: i made a small modification to your css just so it will be transparent, but if you want more modifications i suggest you use some developer tools and check what css classes the buttons have and after that rewrite them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buttons's backgound is set by using `background-image` in `td`s. This should work ([here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/TbTxG/2/)):
**JS**:

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
    text: month,    
    cls: "test",
    // ...
});
```

**CSS**:

```css
.test td {
    background-position: 1000px 1000px;
}
```